# Google Scripts - send meeting invitation with text in email body

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tool programmed in VBA that sends meeting invitations with additional text in body, plus it can send PDF attachments too, or any type of attachment, all in one email. Example is in the picture:

[email with meeting invitation, body text and attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZesI.png)

Is it possible to achieve this in Google Scripts?

Until now, I have only found methods to send meeting invitation (createEvent method), but it seems impossible to find anything about adding text in the email body or attachments?

Are there any other methods in Google Scripts that can help me to achieve example from the picture?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to send text an PDF attachments in Gmail?

Comment: I wanted to know if it is possible to achieve look of the email from the picture using Google Scripts. In Google Scripts I know that it is possible to send meeting invitation to someone, but only meeting invitation. Now I want to know if it is possible to add additional text or even attachment in the same email + meeting invitation?